# Get all the characters after the 3rd hypen (-)

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

I have column TrackNo with values like

```
8070444981-010023-013123-INBBTC-C
601724-072923-078923-INAAAX-B
```

I need to get the values from the 3rd hypen example

```
-INBBTC-C
-INAAAX-B
```

I tried substring,charindex but it is not working for **both the scenarios**

```
select substring( Trackno,
charindex('-', TrackNo , (charindex('-', TrackNo , 1))
+charindex('-', TrackNo, (charindex('-', TrackNo , 1))+1)),20) 
from table
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/Hv-a1Ggr You have a spurious `(charindex('-', TrackNo , 1)) +` on the second line.

Comment: I don't get why so many people do such strange string manipulation in SQL. Generally, SQL, and especially SQL Server are not good in these things and not done for these things. It is far better to either separate the strings and save them in different columns or to do string manipulations in the application.

Comment: @JonasMetzler what would sql people on stackoverflow do with their time if substring and pivot questions disappeared

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please try the following solution based on XML and XQuery.

The XPath predicate  `/root/r[position() ge 4]` is doing the job for your scenario:

> Get all the characters after the 3rd hypen (-)

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Trackno VARCHAR(100));  
INSERT INTO @tbl (Trackno) VALUES 
('8070444981-010023-013123-INBBTC-C'),
('601724-072923-078923-INAAAX-B');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '-';

SELECT t.* 
    , REPLACE(c.query('data(/root/r[position() ge 4])')
        .value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'), SPACE(1), @separator) AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(Trackno, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| ID | Trackno | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8070444981-010023-013123-INBBTC-C | INBBTC-C |
| 2 | 601724-072923-078923-INAAAX-B | INAAAX-B |

Comment: This giving the result but Can u share me /is there anythig with short solution as it is used in select statement of SP which have huge data with multiple joins

Comment: The proposed solution will work in your SP: (1) Add `CROSS APPLY` under your real table with joins, (2) `Add REPLACE(...) as result` to your `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL 2022, you can use `string_split` with the optional ordinal argument, and grab whichever pieces you want (after splitting on `-`).

Barring that, you can brute force the piece with nested `charindex` calls, like you've done. You just need to make sure you're offsetting each chunk correctly so you're not slicing in the wrong place.

```
;with trackingNumbers (TrackNo) as
(
    select '8070444981-010023-013123-INBBTC-C'
    union all select '601724-072923-078923-INAAAX-B'
), b as
(
    select
        TrackNo,
        FirstIndex = charindex('-', TrackNo),
        SecondIndex = charindex
            (
                '-', 
                TrackNo, 
                charindex
                (
                    '-', 
                    TrackNo
                ) + 1
            ),
        ThirdIndex = charindex
            (
                '-', 
                TrackNo, 
                charindex
                (
                    '-', 
                    TrackNo, 
                    charindex
                    (
                        '-', 
                        TrackNo
                    ) + 1
                ) + 1
            )
    from trackingNumbers
)
select *,
LastTwo = substring(TrackNo, ThirdIndex + 1, 8000)
from b
```

There are other ways you can do it by replacing various values in your string to coax it into the form of JSON or XML data if you want, but I'll avoid those in the interest of addressing your original attempted approach.

**EDIT**
Just as a bonus, here's how you could do it with successive cross applies, if you want to go that route.

```
;with trackingNumbers (TrackNo) as
(
    select '8070444981-010023-013123-INBBTC-C'
    union all select '601724-072923-078923-INAAAX-B'
)
select 
    LastTwo = substring(TrackNo, d.ThirdIndex + 1, 8000),
    FirstIndex,
    SecondIndex,
    ThirdIndex
from trackingNumbers a
cross apply
(
    select FirstIndex = charindex('-', TrackNo)
) b
cross apply
(
    select SecondIndex = charindex('-', TrackNo, b.FirstIndex + 1)
) c
cross apply
(
    select ThirdIndex = charindex('-', TrackNo, c.SecondIndex + 1)
) d
```

Comment: Instead of `len(TrackNo)` just do 4000 or 8000 or whatever. No reason to make one of the CPUs go off and calculate a length for every row.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 The length is stored in a prefix, it's not just a null-terminated C string.

Comment: Could improve this by putting duplicate calculations into a series of `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`

Comment: @Charlieface Are you suggesting LEN() is zero cost compared to a constant? Whether it’s _actually_ calculating the length or retrieving it from the page, it’s still not free and doesn’t buy you anything except _maybe_ protecting you from a future data type change.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 No, I'm saying it just doesn't do anything like reading the whole string. The length is already in memory, it's stored right next to the rest of the string (like a BSTR or a .Net string). It's not zero cost, but the cost isn't that high. I agree it's not necessary though.

Answer (score 0):

```
with [table] (Trackno) as (
select '8070444981-010023-013123-INBBTC-C' union
select '601724-072923-078923-INAAAX-B')

select substring(Trackno,
            0 + charIndex('-', TrackNo,
            1 + charIndex('-', TrackNo,
            2 + charIndex('-', Trackno)))
            , 20) as [Result]
from [table]
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SvWti8qG)